# cast dictionary elements of different types

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsnumber

I am using such code to get JSON from server:

```
var jsonresult = NSArray()

do {
    jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
}
```

It helps me to get an array of dictionaries in `jsonresult` variable.

Then I am looping through array to add all dictionaries to another array.

```
for i in jsonresult {
    print(i)
    self.otherArray.append(i as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
}
```

I am using Dictionary type because there are strings values as well as Double values.

Problem is that after data is inserted I can not use "double" values. I get such error: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10c472860) to 'NSNumber'

Yes, I know that I can use `(value as! NSString).doubleValue` but it would be better to cast NSTaggedPointerString into NSNumber in the begining.

Any ideas how can I do it? Maybe I can cast each element of dictionary while adding them to `self.otherArray`?

Comment: You're asking for X, but I have an Y solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34801548/2227743 Just a suggestion, of course. The problam is that using Dictionary<String, AnyObject> will always bring problems with casting on the other side. Better use objects.