# Increment a value in 'NSMutableArray'

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to increment a value in NSMutableArray when an action is done and it is giving me the following error

`Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'int'`.

`self.itemsArray[tag][itemType]!![itemType]!!["likeCount"] as! Int = self.itemsArray[tag][itemType]!![itemType]!!["likeCount"] as! Int +1`

this was my line of code . And I'm pretty sure thats an Int. I'm trying increment the value present in likeCount.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: it looks like you should not use dictionaries for your use case. I would rather use arrays of custom structs, for example. Dictionaries with nested values are not the most convenient data structures in Swift. At all. :)

Comment: Can you give me some tips on how to create custom structs for my JSON data

Comment: Without knowing your data, I can't give you a tailored example. But have a look at this for starters, it can give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34801548/2227743